# How to save chunk of information between two words to a file?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a following file:

**old_file**

```
new_file
  Some string.
end

Text in the middle that is not supposed to go to any of files.

new_file
  Another text.
end
```

How using regex can I create two files with the following content:

**file1**

```
new_file
  Some string.
end
```

**file2**

```
new_file
  Another text.
end
```

How can I get information which is between keywords '**new_file**' and '**end**' to write it to the file?

Comment: If you can read the file in as one string, use [`/^new_file$.*?^end$/m`](http://rubular.com/r/MeVuqOfpyz)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could I create several files If I read the old file once at a time?

Comment: Another way is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632784/ruby-print-selected-lines-of-text-in-between-2-strings

Comment: No idea what you mean. You get all matches first, then create files to save those texts. Your previous question showed the code you were using: you read the file line by line. See the link above to an [answer for a similar scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6632803/3832970). The right answer depends on what approach you want to take, and I'd rather you posted the code you have.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My aim is just to create files each of which contains different **new_file end** block. Frankly, I don't know which approach would be more efficient in this case - reading by line or reading file at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files are not that large, you can read them in as a string, (use `File.read(file_name)`), and then run the following regex:

```
file_contents.scan(/^new_file$.*?^end$/m).select { |block| WRITE_TO_FILE_CODE_HERE }
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/MeVuqOfpyz)

The `^new_file$.*?^end$` regex matches `new_file` that is a whole line content, then 0+ any characters as few as possible (incl. a newline as `/m` modifier is used), and then `end` (a whole line).

Else, you may adapt [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6632803/3832970) as

```
printing = false
File.open(my_file).each_line do |line|
  printing = true if line =~ /^new_file$/      
  puts line if printing
  printing = false if line =~ /^end$/
end
```

Open the file when the starting line is found, write to it where `puts line` is in the example above, and close when `printing false` occurs.

Comment: Great answer. Can I check everything and then accept?

Comment: Sure, take your time.

Comment: Виктор, You are truly great ;) I wish I knew regexp as good as you. Maybe you could bring up a couple of books?

Comment: I learnt a lot from posting regex related answers here on SO. *Mastering Regular Expressions* (O'Reilly Media) is considered the best book on regexps, however, you may get a good gist of how to use regex by completing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com), reading stuff at [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) and [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com). Practice regex at [Rubular](http://rubular.com) and [Regex101](http://regex101.com).

Comment: Much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also read the file chunk by chunk by changing what constitutes a "line" in ruby:

```
File.open("file1.txt", "w") do |file1|
  File.open("file2.txt", "w") do |file2|
    enum = IO.foreach("old_file.txt", sep="\n\n")
    file1.puts enum.next.strip
    enum.next  #discard
    file2.puts enum.next.strip
  end #automatically closes file2
end #automatically closes file1
```

By designating the separator as "\n\n" ruby will read all the characters up to and including two consecutive newlines--and return that as a "line".

Answer (score 0):

If that kind of format is fixed, then you may try this [`(new_file\n.*\nend)`](https://regex101.com/r/nI8sP6/3)