# How can I use code template in android when creating project from command line?

Tags: android, templates, command-line

I have used android code templates in eclipse such as blank activity,login activity etc. I want to use these templates while creating project from command line. How can I do this?

Comment: use this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html       : I want to use this from command line

Answer (score 0):

You can write and render these templates (or any other template you want to create) using Ruby's [ERB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby#erb) gem.

From http://www.ictforu.com/index.php/Ruby/erb-ruby.html:

> ERB is an abbreviation for Embedded Ruby
>
> ERB is a feature of Ruby that enables user to dynamically generate any
>   kind of text from templates. The templates combine plain text with
>   Ruby code for variable substitution and flow control, which makes them
>   easy to write and maintain.
>
> ERB is commonly used in Rails platform to generate the webpages, It is
>   also used in generating XML files, Source code, etc.

Although it's quite common in `Ruby on Rails` you can use it wherever you want ;-)

I suggest you to check:

- [ERB documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)
- [How do I execute ruby template files (ERB) without a web server from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980547/how-do-i-execute-ruby-template-files-erb-without-a-web-server-from-command-lin)