# How to create android template project from command line?

Tags: android

android project create from command line as command

```
android create lib-project --name <your_project_name> \
--target <target_ID> \
--path path/to/your/project \
--package <your_library_package_namespace>
```

but there is no option to select project from template.

Comment: seems like this has been asked here as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028047/how-can-i-use-code-template-in-android-when-creating-project-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the templates are used from the platform folder which is dependent on your target_ID. For instance, if your command line specifies --target 10 then the template used will be from the path /platforms/android-10/templates

I am not sure if you are able to specify a template folder explicitly during the create command.